# How can I query select all inputs from table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the input from a table form. The table has but 2 columns how can I get the input from these? I want to have a different var for each column of items? Should I use an array? This is my table:

```
       <table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
                <th scope="col">Gewicht x KG</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX="10" STEP="1" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

What is the best way to get around this?  I tried to select by tag name.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Also there is lots of examples if you google a bit

Comment: Maybe it's because you wrote inputs' tags in uppercase?

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski case doesn't really matter for html source code, as far as tags go

Comment: Your inputs need a name like ```name="data[col1][]"```

Comment: @justrusty why?

Comment: An application of selecting the rows, then mapping each row to a selection of its inner inputs can result in an outputted 2 dimensional array of all the inputs.

Comment: I cant bacause the table changes size dynamically by the use of slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a quick one for jQuery:

Replace tableid with the id of your table

```
var col1_Array = $('#tableid td:nth-child(1)').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get()​;

var col2_Array = $('#tableid td:nth-child(2)').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get()​;
```

Comment: Does that return the first of second column? what exactly did you do?

Comment: This is a template - replace tableId with your real id and try via console.debug what you get - Sorry for not doing all the work for you